# building a docker image in AWS with CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I was using `gcloud`before and could build a docker image on a GCP machine as follows:

```
gcloud builds submit ./my-docker-dir/ -t eu.gcr.io/<path>/<component>:<tag> --timeout 30m --machine-type e2-highcpu-32\n
```

Is there a similar AWS equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such alternative. With AWS you use `docker` to `build` & `push` to ECR.

An example workflow would be:

0. Create a `docker` file and build it with:

```sh
docker build -t hello-world .
```

1. Authenticate your Docker client to the Amazon ECR registry to which you intend to push your image.

```sh
aws ecr get-login-password --region region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com
```

2. Create an ECR repository

```
aws ecr create-repository \
    --repository-name hello-world \
    --image-scanning-configuration scanOnPush=true \
    --region region
```

3. Tag the docker image you've built.

```
docker tag hello-world:latest aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/hello-world:latest
```

4. Push it to your ECR repo.

```sh
docker push aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/hello-world:latest
```

Comment: Yeah, the issue is I wanted to use a powerful machine on AWS side to do the building. If I understand you correctly, there is no easy CLI submission thing that would also spin the machine

Comment: I'm not aware of a single `awscli` command that does *all* the things you want in one go. You could chain a couple of command, with some prior preps, but I guess that's not what you want. In other words, there's no direct counter command to that from GCP.